# could not connect to database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Home::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51

updating autoload.php giving http:500 error

Comment: Please add the line of code that's producing the error.

Comment: Are you loading the database library? Is the database config set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the db library first. In

autoload.php :

```
$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be any the following:

You must make sure you have set up your database details correctly in the application/config/database.php file. Instruction on what to fill in here are explained on this page of the manual: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Or it could be that you first need to load the database library by writing the following code above where you have written your query:

```
$this->load->database();
```

And to run your query, the code should look roughly like:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM mytable');
```

Answer (score 0):

you must go to autoload and replace $autoload['libraries'] with this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation');`

Answer (score 0):

the guide says:

> You can tell the model loading function to auto-connect by passing
>   TRUE (boolean) via the third parameter, and connectivity settings, as
>   defined in your database config file will be used:

```
$this->load->model('model_name', 'model_alias', TRUE);
```

and you can access the model by its alias like this:

```
$this->model_alias->method();
```

or without alias:

```
$this->load->model('model_name', '', TRUE);
```

and access the model:

```
$this->model_name->method();
```